# leetcode 56: heap-buffer-overflow

Tags: c

Here is the code:

```
#define BASESIZE 20
#define INCREASE 50

int partition(int *nums, int low, int high)
{
    int i=low;
    int j=high;
    int pivot[2]={ nums[i], nums[i+1] };

    while(i<j) {
        while(i<j && nums[j]>=pivot[0]) j-=2;
        nums[i]=nums[j];
        nums[i+1]=nums[j+1];

        while(i<j && nums[i]<=pivot[0]) i+=2;
        nums[j]=nums[i];
        nums[j+1]=nums[i+1];
    }
    nums[i]=pivot[0];
    nums[i+1]=pivot[1];

    return i;
}

void quickSort(int *nums, int low, int high)
{
    if(low<high) {
        int loc=partition(nums, low, high);
        quickSort(nums, low, loc-2);
        quickSort(nums, loc+2, high);
    }
}

int** merge(int** intervals, int intervalsSize, int* intervalsColSize, int* returnSize, int** returnColumnSizes){
    int **ret=NULL;
    *returnSize=0;

    if(intervalsSize==1) {
        *returnSize+=1;
        *returnColumnSizes=malloc(sizeof(int)*(*returnSize));
        if(!(*returnColumnSizes)) exit(-1);
        (*returnColumnSizes)[0]=2;
        return intervals;
    }

    quickSort(*intervals, 0, (intervalsSize-1)*2);

    int *tmp=malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    if(!tmp) exit(-1);
    tmp[0]=(*intervals)[0];
    tmp[1]=(*intervals)[1];

    int size=BASESIZE;
    ret=malloc(sizeof(int*)*size);
    if(!ret) exit(-1);
    *returnSize+=1;
    ret[0]=tmp;

    *returnColumnSizes=malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    if(!(*returnColumnSizes)) exit(-1);
    (*returnColumnSizes)[0]=2;

    int *preS=&ret[0][0]; 
    int *preE=&ret[0][1];
    int *nextS=*intervals+2; 
    int *nextE=nextS+1;

    while(nextS<*intervals+2*intervalsSize-1) {
        assert(*preS<=*preE && *nextS<=*nextE);

        if(*preE<*nextS) {
            // 1. insert, change the size if need
            *returnSize+=1;

            if(*returnSize>size) {
                size+=INCREASE;
                ret=realloc(ret, sizeof(int*)*size);
                if(!ret) exit(-1);
                *returnColumnSizes=realloc(*returnColumnSizes, sizeof(int)*size);
                if(!(*returnColumnSizes)) exit(-1);
            }

            tmp=malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
            if(!tmp) exit(-1);
            tmp[0]=*nextS; 
            tmp[1]=*nextE;

            ret[*returnSize-1]=tmp;
            (*returnColumnSizes)[*returnSize-1]=2;

            // 2. move
            preS=&ret[*returnSize-1][0];
            preE=preS+1;
        } else if(*preE>=*nextS && *preE<=*nextE) {
            ret[*returnSize-1][1]=*nextE;
        } else if(*preE>=*nextE) {

        }

        nextS=nextS+2;
        nextE=nextS+1;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Here is the message:

```
=================================================================
==42==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000058 at pc 0x55dcae61a270 bp 0x7ffc93ca68c0 sp 0x7ffc93ca68b0
READ of size 4 at 0x602000000058 thread T0
    #4 0x7f652b05f0b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
0x602000000058 is located 0 bytes to the right of 8-byte region [0x602000000050,0x602000000058)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f652bca4bc8 in malloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10dbc8)
    #4 0x7f652b05f0b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c047fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c047fff8000: fa fa 00 fa fa fa 00 00 fa fa 00[fa]fa fa 00 fa
  0x0c047fff8010: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==42==ABORTING
```

On my own machine, I test the code, using not only "valgrind ./a.out", but also "gcc -O -g -fsanitize=address test.c";  "./a.out" . There is no problem.
However, when I run the code online, the message tells me there is heap-buffer-overflow problem.
But I fail correct it.
What's wrong with code， how to correct?

Comment: This looks needlessly complicated. Consider splitting allocation and the algorithm into different functions. Let the algorithm work with caller-allocated arrays when possible.

Comment: First you should figure out how to reproduce the problem for yourself. I suppose you don't know what input leetcode is supplying for the crash? Test different inputs then. Once you know how to reproduce it and if you still don't know how to fix it, help us reproduce it as well ([mre]) and add an explanation what the code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: What is "leetcode 56"? Can we see `main` as well? Or better yet, a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: If this is a coding challenge, make sure your solution can solve the whole range of specified inputs, and any corner cases. The symptom is often the result of *undefined behaviour* somewhere in the code, but you only posted a fragment so it can't be compiled. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried. May I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you sure `loc + 2` and `loc - 2` inside `quickSort()` is correct? Note that `merge()` can call `quickSort` with `low = 0` and `high = 2`.

Comment: I'm so sorry. The problem is here: https://leetcode-cn.com/problems/merge-intervals

Comment: I modified the code. I allocate all space of `*returnColumnSizes` one time after I get the value of `*returnSize`. But the heap-buffer-overflow remains, and I still cannot solve the problem.

Comment: It seems to me that you shouldn't need to allocate additional memory for this. After sorting the list of intervals you should be able to process them in place, back to front, merging the current interval into the previous one if they overlap or touch. Of course whenever you merge you'll need to iterate through the tail, closing the gap that emerged.

Answer (score 0):

The `quickSort` function is based on the wrong assumption that the `intervals` were stored in contiguous memory, i. e. the assumption intervals[i]+2 == intervals[i+1] is wrong. Therefore, the call

```
    quickSort(*intervals, 0, (intervalsSize-1)*2);
```

which passes only intervals[0] is inadequate; instead `intervals` has to be passed and the sorting function modified accordingly to process independently allocated intervals.